# Dynamic Control is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, panel

Question: I have dynamic control that i will put to pnlGetValues
After i click a button i cannot find it in my loop.

```
string _name = Regex.Replace(_response.Name, @"\s+", "");
_dynamicTextbox.ID = "txtID";
_response.Required.ToString();
_dynamicTextbox.AutoPostBack = false;
_dynamicLabel.Text += "" + "<br><br>";
pnlGetValues.Controls.Add(_dynamicTextbox);
pnlGetValues.Controls.Add(_dynamicLabel);

 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control _control in pnlGetValues.Controls)
        {
            pnlGetValues.Controls.Count.ToString();
            if (_control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox _value = (TextBox)_control.Findcontrol("txtID");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you recreating the control after post-back?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if (_control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox _value = (TextBox)_pnlGetValues.Findcontrol("txtID");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be `FindControl` and not `Findcontrol`